# Primes that are approximately twice other primes

Tags: prime-numbers

Are there infinitely many pairs of primes of the form $p,2p-1$?

What about $p,2p+1$?

Comment: The latter type are called Sophi-Germain primes.  See the Wikipedia page.  It is not known if there are infinitely many such pairs.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Germain_prime

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickson%27s_conjecture

Comment: See [OEIS A$005382$](http://oeis.org/A005382).

Comment: is 2p-1 also an accepted value?

Comment: Accepted in terms of Dickson's conjecture?  Yes.

Answer (score 4):

However,
for any $\epsilon > 0$,
there are infinitely many pairs of primes
$p, q$
such that
$|\frac{p}{q}-2|
< \epsilon
$.

This is a very special case of
the result proved in
Hobby, D., D. M. Silbeger, Quotients of primes, Amer. Math. Monthly, Vol. 100, 1993,
No. 1, 50–52,
that
the ratio
$\frac{p}{q}$
taken over all pairs of primes
is dense in the positive reals.